# Why would spaceships still have acrylic/glass windows when force fields are cheap and reliable?

Tags: technology, space-travel, spaceships, materials

Force field technology has come a long way. The latest energy-efficient engines can guarantee stable energy output in any situation, making force fields extremely reliable and very cost effective compared to acrylic and glass. Power failure is a thing of the past. Force fields eliminate the need for decompression chambers because the fields can allow both organic and inorganic objects to pass through unharmed while preventing air from escaping. Given such a future, why would any spaceship still have acrylic/glass window?

Comment: By "screen", I assume you mean a window on the ship. Correct?

Comment: @SRM Yes similar to the function of a windscreen of a car

Comment: Why would they have a hull? If you can make force field windows why not make a whole ship a force bubble?

Comment: If force fields were that reliable, they indeed would not need 'glass'.  But it strains believably to suggest that even in times of accident or combat that the power wouldn't so much as flicker.

Comment: Why would spaceships have windows when imaging sensors & displays are cheap & reliable?

Comment: Also, its transparent aluminum, not acrylic/glass.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The short answer is that they wouldn't, but not for the reasons stated in the question. Longer answer is as follows;

First of all, even assuming that power is ultra-reliable, it's good engineering practice to build things where the safety position is in the 'power off' mode. Modern nuclear power plants (for example) don't need power to insert the control rods that slow down the reaction; they need power to *retract* them. When the power cuts out, the control rods fall back into place, effectively shutting down the reaction while there is no power, and therefore no monitoring or control.

A window is the perfect 'power off' safety solution in your case; if the ship is the first one in 100 years to lose internal power, then your crew is still safe from suffocation, at least in the short term. With force fields, they would instantly be sucked out into the vacuum of space to suffocate. That's not a good 'power off' scenario and no-one in their right mind would build a ship like that no matter how reliable the power supply appears to be.

Second, it should be pointed out that with the exception of airlocks, they probably wouldn't use glass windows anyway; they'd most likely have display screens on the inside and closed circuit cameras on the outside. This has 2 advantages. The first is that there is no structural weakness in the ship caused by putting a window into a solid bulkhead. The second is that you can look through every 'window' from a single display screen, making it more versatile a system.

As for airlocks, you'd still have a blast door that you'd shut for the majority of the time because of the 'power off' safety consideration, even if it was only for the psychological comfort of your passengers and crew.

Finally, there is no such thing (even in the future) as a 'reliable' power source. EVERY power source either contains or generates power and releases it in a controlled fashion. It's that control which often generates the issues and when the control is less than optimal, the power can be released in an uncontrolled fashion. Think Fukashima or Chernobyl; in both cases, massive energy releases occurred because of unforeseen (read as unplanned for) circumstances.

What if your ship takes longer to get where it's going? Runs out of fuel? Runs into an asteroid? Gets attacked? Something can always go wrong with a power source. People who think of something as reliable (IMHO) just don't have good imaginations.

Bottom line is that you don't want the power to go off on one of these things for the first time in centuries to be the one time that you get asked why you put a permanent hole in the side of your ship in the first place.

Comment: "*It's good engineering practice to build things where the safety position is in the 'power off' mode.*" This is called Fail-safe (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-safe).  The opposite is *Failing badly* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failing_badly) and OP's scenario is a perfect example of that.

Comment: "and no-one in their right mind would build a ship like that" ... maybe a prison ship. "Anyone sabotages this vehicle, everyone goes whoosh, so don't do that."

Comment: @SRM: Why build windows in a prison ship?

Comment: @JoeBloggs to discourage the prisoners from sabotage? I know; it's a circular argument but it's a fun one. ;)

Comment: @TimBII: Aaah, they’re not windows: They’re emergency Prisoner Offload Portals, or ‘POP’s.

Comment: @JoeBloggs So prisoners can see what they're missing out on. It is easy to forget the green hills  and blue skies of Earth or the red mountains of Mars when sealed away from them. But it twists the knife if prisoners can see what they have lost every day out the windows.

Comment: @SRM: I’d just give them screens and a video archive of some travel programmes.

Comment: @JoeBloggs They might look away. I was thinking of the entire outer shell might just be a force field... if I was designing a really awful prison ship.

Comment: @SRM: oh, if that’s the game then a deep space prison ship might be even better. Nothing quite like floating alone in the void to drive a prisoner nuts.

Comment: @TimBII I like this answer, but it occurs to me that the screens for windows case has a similar shortcoming in that if the system is down there will be no way to see outside.  Not that this is a catastrophic failure, but wouldn't this "fail-safe" line of thinking preclude the replacement of windows with screens?

Comment: @ben sure, but it's a tradeoff. Windows can fail because of structural weakness, screens can fail for electrical reasons. It's all about which you think is the biggest risk for your system.

Comment: @JoeBloggs Ah, you mean prisoner suicide boxes... taking all the guards with them if there are any onboard...^^

Comment: Hmm, while I like the argument, I'd add one caveeat: People might actually build such a ship IF the force fields give a major advantage over glass, like three time the travel speed or such (which admittedly is unlikely, but...). After all, we build things that fall down and have a high chance to kill everyone inside in the process when the power suddenly fails completely (planes, helicopters). (yes for many there is a significant chance to still land them, if nothing else is broken, still.)

Comment: Note that windows aren't terribly useful for most of space travel, because usually there's nothing to see.  They might have use for some docking/landing, but a screen is going to be a fairly reliable system to begin with.

Comment: As commented, if power goes, so do the viewing monitors.  A flash thought occurs to me of a compromise between windows and viewing monitors:  a periscope function.  A hard optic connection that doesn't mess with the hull integrity too much that leads to a manual means of having a peep outside.

Answer (score 8):

there is reliable and there is *reliable*, solids work even without power, even in a magnetic or radiation storm. Your power source may not fail but connections can be cut or damaged. And of course you have power usage, a force field will need a lot a power a plastic plate needs none. Solids also offer protection from radiation and micrometeoroids which your stated force fields will not.  Finally you have purposeful loss of power, turning power off for maintenance is pretty normal for safety and not having to run extension cords to all your windows to do routine maintenance is a big bonus.

Comment: This should be the main reason. It is said (it's not true but a good concept) that while the NASA spent billions developing a pen that can write in zero-gravity, URSS used pencils. Why would someone complicated a design when there is a cheaper, more failure tolerant and overall SIMPLER solution?

Comment: @ESL that is actually an urban legend, both sides used and quickly abandoned pencils , because graphite shaving in a zero g environment are a huge fire hazard. And Nasa did not spend a dime designing the space pen. https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/the-write-stuff/

Comment: I know, that's why i write "it's not true". But this myth is "a good concept" of KISS.

Answer (score 4):

**Because maybe the field needs help, or maybe you want to keep people from getting zapped by the field.**

> the fields can allow both organic and inorganic objects to pass
>   through unharmed while preventing air from escaping.

If the force field is only good for gas, then probably you do not want your stuff falling outside the ship when you turn a sharp corner.  Or stuff outside falling into the ship - though that outside stuff can be moving fast and hopefully you are not counting on an acrylic windshield for meteoroids.  The areas protected by your futuristic fields are separate controlled zones and you want to control access to these zones by things and people.

---

If you assert that your force field can exclude people and things as effectively as gas, then maybe it is unpleasant for people to be excluded by a force field.  It hurts.  You do not want to get out of the shower and accidentally walk into one wearing just a towel.   An acrylic shield is a reminder to humans in the vicinity: *Force Field here*.  *Keep arms and legs out of the force field*.

You could use a chainlink fence for that instead, or "CAUTION" yellow tape.  But the acrylic looks cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

For all the reasons mentioned, such as fail safe design and power consumption, but also for the sake of good story writing, your systems should make sense. Power is not infinite. If it is, where is the fun in that? Technology is not perfect. Power could fail, control could be cut, and while assuming you wanted to have windows for aesthetic or stylistic reasons, they should have both glass/acrylic and force fields on the outside. You can establish limitations in your writing, and then use that as a plot device later to add tension. I've long dreamed of a space faring vessel with an observation deck that was just a big transparent canopy. Probably a better view than a screen. But that would be a special area of the ship, with pressurized bulkheads to prevent decompression if the canopy was breached. a wonderful place to contemplate the mysteries of the universe or to bring a date, but it wouldn't compromise the entire ship if damaged.

Answer (score 1):

You can't never trust in things like your energy production or a force field.

What would happen to the ship is it run out of energy? For example: an electromagnectic pulse could shut down your reactors or damage the internal system of your shields and all the people would die almost instantly. That ship is extremelly vulnerable to lack of fuel, hack, reactor overload, EMP, failure, etc.

A good engineer always designs things with double check/security systems, like a forcefield **and** a windows (also, you would use a camera and an screen instead...). An engineer would dessign ships able to hold life even on a power off situation like the described above.

If the ship accidentally has a failure it mustn't produce a bigger problem, it must try to fix or prevent it, i.e: if the ship shut down, the airlock must automatically close itself **not open**.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there won't be glass or acrylic screens at all. In planes, the windows are actually a weak point.

You can use screens and cameras to emulate windows without the structural weakness of a window

See [Windowless planes](https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/vvbygj/windowless-airplanes-future)

Over the next twenty or so years, windows will disappear from aircraft

Shields will make a good backup and emergency repair but you can't really use shields as structural strength.

Answer (score 0):

If the force field behaves how you want it to, there is indeed no need for glass or acrylic screens. I believe this was mentioned in one of the star trek movies/episodes were they didn't actually have any glass in the windows.

The point of screens in most sci-fi, even when force fields are available, is that your force field can only only withstand so much, before it is destroyed/penetrated and so one. When this happens, your screens will protect the personnel on board, instead of creating an instant vacuum and sucking everyone out.

Secondly, it would be far more energy efficient to only use the force field when its required, rather than projecting it 24/7 all year. Space journeys can take a long time and a space ship can only hold so much fuel and spare parts before you need a bigger spaceship, which requires more fuel and so on.

Answer (score 0):

**Why should there be 'windows' at all**

Why would a space vessel need windows when regardless of what they are made from they still represent a potential 'failure point' in the hull of your vessel. Simply put force fields or not you want the strongest hull possible.

This is especially the case the same amount of space taken up by any given sized window you can put multiple sets of **cameras** in the same location. In fact you can embed a whole range of different sensor types around the hull. At the push of a button anyone with access to a screen can see the external view from virtually any angle around the ship in whatever spectrum of light they were interested in *and* focus the view on points of interest.

If its a passenger ship, and you  want you just put large thin monitors on the inside of the hull at suitable locations displaying the fixed viewpoint any passerby would see if there was actually a window located at that spot. Alternatively if the ship was large enough you might install a one or couple of 'viewing' stations with 'real' windows (and force fields for redundancy) but as I said  in reality passengers would get the same clarity from high tech optical devices so why bother.

The other issue; **Forget bridges located at the 'front' of the ship**. For the same reasons mentioned above the bridge/control room would be located wherever was safest for it inside deep inside the hull. The Captain doesn't need to be a the 'front' of the ship looking out a window to maintain situation awareness. He has access to passive sensors, ladar, radar and whatever other high tech instruments you want to give him PLUS cameras. All of which will let him 'see' everything for billions of miles around without the need for a single window. And he would see it all from his Command 'deck' located in the heart of the ship near other important systems/rooms he might need quick access to.

Answer (score 0):

Force fields would rely on power. Power can be shut off. Power can fail. Thus windows could be vacated with the flick of a switch or the crash of a computer or control system. Not the ideal protection system. Ideally, you'd have standard windows and doors and still have the force field in place. Acrylic and glass would not generally hold up in spacecraft in interstellar flight. Dust and debris would penetrate them. Radiation would penetrate most metals even. Force fields will be required for interstellar fight but I suspect they will not serve as windows without a secondary means of shutting the hull up tight.